# Pandas Shift multiple rows faster based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I looked at some solutions in stackoverflow but haven't found something that works for me

I have a dataframe:

```
column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4 | ...
  1           nan         1         nan
  2            3          4         nan
  3           nan         5         nan
 ...          ...        ...        ...
```

I want to shift all rows that the `column_2` has a none value

So I did this:

```
import math
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if not math.isnan(row["column_2]):
        df.iloc[index, :] = df.iloc[index, :].shift()
```

and it works. this is the output:

```
column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4 | ...
 nan           1         nan         1        # this row changed
  2            3          4         nan
 nan           3         nan         5        # this row changed
 ...          ...        ...        ...
```

The problem is that it is SUPER SLOW

Is there a way to achieve the same thing faster?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with `axis=1` only for filtered rows:

```
m = df["column_2"].isna()
df[m] = df[m].shift(axis=1)
print (df)
   column_1  column_2  column_3  column_4
0       NaN       1.0       NaN       1.0
1       2.0       3.0       4.0       NaN
2       NaN       3.0       NaN       5.0
```

Alternative solution:

```
df = df.mask(df["column_2"].isna(), df.shift(axis=1))
```

Comment: this returns an `error: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: @Kevin - For me working correct, can you check alternative?